# Find the values of the positive constants $k$ and $c$ in trigonometric inequality

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Find the values of the positive constants $k$ and $c$ such that

$-600\leq k(16\cos ⁡x-63\sin ⁡x)+c\leq 700$

for all values of $x$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE, try to use MathJax.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = 16 \cos x -63 \sin x$ in the interval $[0,2\pi]$ , we want to find the maximum and minimum value of $f$, $f$ is continues and in closed interval so such values exists.

$f(0)=f(2\pi) = 16$ and $f'(x) = -16 \sin x-63 \cos x=0$ so  $ -16 \sin x = 63 \cos x$ and so $ \tan x = -\frac{63}{16}$ so $ x \approx 1.819506316,4.961098969$ , (you can prove that one point gives you maximum and one give you minimum).

The maximum value is $65$ and the minimum value is $-65$, and so we want $k,c$ such that $ -65 k+c=-600 $ and $65 k + c = 700$ the only pair the satisfy the equation is $k=10,c=50$.